# Save app data in kivy on Android

Tags: android, python, kivy

Say I was making a fitness app where you can make your out workout. When you have configured the workout you would want to save it. How do I add this function so that when he exits the app and opens it again, he can view his workouts?

I am working specifically on Android.

This could be used to save local game saves and data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe Kivy has a module that deals with this. Though it is still(at the time of writing) experimental. Look here: http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.storage.html#module-kivy.storage

They appear to be using Pickle to store the data, according to [this.](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.storage.dictstore.html#)

If that doesn't work for some reason, 
what about using Pickle/cPickle yourself? If you don't know what those are, Google them now.
Then you could store user settings or workouts in a dict and pickle that dict, saving the
info to the sdcard as a simple text file, which shouldn't take up much space at all.

As far as I know, cPickle is a faster implementation of Pickle due to being written in C or possibly Cython, I am not sure. Hope any of this helps.

It's worth noting that it's possible to save text files to the Android device. I recently made a game with Kivy where I was doing just that, storing high scores in plain text.

Comment: Could this be done with images?(Such as images for a game's background)

Comment: @Paarthri I'm not sure, but I don't think so. If you're including images with kivy, as part of an app or game, then I don't see the point in trying to store them in this way anyway... but without any context it's hard to answer that.

Comment: On Android do we need any kind of permission to save this pickle to SD or internal memory? I did make an implementation that saves an object to a file on the 'on_stop' method and should restore it on the 'on_start' method. It worked fine on my PC, but when I deploy and run it on Android it always starts with the default "no saved data" case, and I have no idea about the location where the pickle file should be saved to check it was really created. Any tips??

Comment: @Claudio It's been while since I did this. But I believe you always need certain permissions to do things on Android, and certainly modifying the SD card would require one. I would google for that permission specifically, and make sure you take into account the version(s) of Android you are targeting as permissions change sometimes I think. You will also need to figure out where you actually can save to on an Android device.. it shouldn't be hard to find out where a normal place to save files on Android is. I don't remember it being too hard to find this stuff. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Totem, yesterday I uploaded a later version of this scheme I developed above and surprisingly it worked (with no permission fiddling), but I was stumped since I could not really find where it was saving the pickle file at all. Searched both through the SD and internal memory into Android... data dirs but couldn't find anything. Really strange, but at least worked?!

Comment: @Claudio Good that it works, be nice to know where the files are going though :p

Comment: @Totem, sure, as soon as I find out I'll update the info here!

Comment: That just says "use a Python dictionary as a store". There's no indication that it's actually persisted anywhere on the device, nor where that would be for each platform.