# Kivy on Android : How to keep local saved file after app update?

Tags: android, kivy

I want to know the correct steps to keep local saved data after app update.

I confirmed the following old question, but I can't solve the issue.
[Save app data in kivy on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289325/save-app-data-in-kivy-on-android)

I tried the following.

1. 1-1:I made android APK with buildozer(command:buildozer android debug). 1-2:And execute 'store.put' method using 'kivy.storage'. then 'hello.json' file was created in the './' directory.
   https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.storage.html

   > 1-1:'./' directory in APK ver.1
   >
   > > main.pyo
   >
   > 1-2:'./' directory in APK ver.1
   >
   > > main.pyo, hello.json(created)
2. 2-1:I made android APK ver.2(same app name as 1.APK). 2-2:After installing in update mode, execute only 'store.get' method using 'kivy.storage'. then method failed because 'hello.json' file was automatically deleted with app update.

   > 2-1:'./' directory in APK ver.2
   >
   > > main.pyo(changed from APK ver.1)
   >
   > 2-2:'./' directory in updated APK
   >
   > > main.pyo(ver.2)
3. I tried changing the output location of the 'hello.json' file but it made no sense.
   e.g. './data/data/[app_name]/files/hello.json' and './data/data/[app_name]/shared_prefs/hello.json'

How can I update my application?

Comment: I don't think an update should remove your saved data. Are you sure you are doing an update as opposed to an uninstall/install?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think if a package name is the same, it will be automatically update mode.The installation message is also described as update.

Comment: I will put a dummy 'hello.json' file and update it and try to confirm the result.

Comment: I put a dummy json file in the './' directory and ran the update. As a matter of course, the original file is not left and replaced with a dummy file...

Comment: Is the `hello.json` file replaced?? Is there a `hello.json` file as part of your APK?

Comment: Yes, the old 'hello.json' file has been replaced by the new 'hello.json' file as a result of the update.'hello.json' file is part of the APK. It is in the same hierarchy  as 'main.py'.

Comment: That explains why it is being replaced. Perhaps you should not include it in your APK, then have your code check for its existence and create a default `hello.json` if one doesn't exist.

Comment: I added a description of the problem. In the first experiment, I did not include the json file in the APK file before and after the update. Probably 'hello.json' has already been deleted by updating the application before main.pyo is executed..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything in the default current directory, which is named `app`, is deleted and replaced on app update. You can place persistent data in the directory *above* this, i.e. `../`, and it should stick around between updates.

You can also use your app's external storage directory, using pyjnius to query the Android API for its location, but I don't have code for that right now.

This isn't especially well documented, I'll try to improve it.

Comment: Wow! I succeeded in keeping the file using '../'! I didn't understand enough about the basic mechanism.Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks @inclement '../' worked with me also. I cannot find the files in the phone storage though. although i print os path and the result is (/data/data/package_name/files/app/.....). When I check Internat storage I find that the /data folder is empty .. I want to check the files just out of curiousity

Comment: Maybe I have to root the device and check. Not the internal storage.

Comment: @KhaledAhmedSobhy As you guess, this directory is not accessible without root.

Comment: @inclement I couldn't find this information in the docs, can you tell me where I should look? Thanks!